# Overlapping sectors on linux volumes

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, diskmanagement

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 VM that's running on Hyper-V 2012 R2 cluster. I needed to extend the space on the VM. The first thing I did was to expand the VHDX file. After doing this, I see a really weird overlapping sectors on the disk. What is happening here? sda2 & sda5 have overlapping (almost identical) sectors.

```
Device     Boot   Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *       2048   999423   997376  487M 83 Linux
/dev/sda2       1001470 20969471 19968002  9.5G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1001472 20969471 19968000  9.5G 8e Linux LVM
```

Comment: This is an old MSDOS-style partition table. While GPT partition tables are the current standard, these are still commonly used in virtual machines and older systems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is normal, SDA2 is an extended partition, which is a special 'container' partition, that contains other partitions.  An extended partitions permits you to bypass the limitation of 4 'primary' partitions that is left over for the DOS days.

You should be able to resize these using gparted/parted.  For safety, you can take a snapshot of your VM before trying to change things, so you can be sure you can undo, if the partitioning goes wrong.

I know what you have is the probably the default partition layout from your distribution, but in the future I strongly suggest you create the LVM as a primary partition, it makes things easier.